# Why can't I patch a class from a different file for my unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a file called `some.py`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from some_folder.some_reader import SomeReader

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.reader = SomeReader(url)
```

and `some_reader.py`:

```
class SomeReader:
    def read_path(self, url):
        return "read_path"
```

and `some_test.py`:

```
from unittest.mock importpatch
from some_folder.some import SomeClass

@patch("some_folder.some_reader.SomeReader")
def test_some_class(mock_some_reader):
    SomeClass("")
```

When I run `some_test`, it seems that the `SomeReader` instantiated is not a mock object, instead it is:

```
SomeReader
<class 'some_folder.some_reader.SomeReader'>
```

Everything seems to work fine if I put `SomeReader` in `some.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

`some.py`:

```py
from some_folder.some_reader import SomeReader


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.reader = SomeReader(url)
```

`some_folder/some_reader.py`:

```py
class SomeReader:
    def read_path(self, url):
        return "read_path"
```

`test_some.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from some import SomeClass


class TestSome(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("some.SomeReader")
    def test_some_class(self, mock_some_reader):
        some = SomeClass("")
        print(some.reader)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test result:

```sh
<MagicMock name='SomeReader()' id='4520784368'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```